# Android - how can I change my 2-column layout to have dynamic widths?

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have a 2 column layout which looks like this:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
     android:layout_width="275dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
     android:textSize="16sp"/>

 <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
     android:layout_width="25dip"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" 
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

But with this approach I just hardcode the widths, and I am not sure what happens on wider on narrower screens. Is there a way to adjust this to use percentages of the width?

Thanks!

Comment: use LinearLayout and set appropriate layout_weight to childrens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify width, or height using percentages, but there's something that is similar - `weightSum` and `layout_weight`. If you for example what your `View` to have width half of a screen, you have to do it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="1.0">
  <View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:layout_width="0dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the container of a `View` (`LinearLayout`) has set `android:weightSum` to `1.0` which means that `1.0` will be 100% of it's width/height. Then if you specify `android:layout_weight` for `View` inside this container to for example `.5` and set it's width or height to `0dp` (this part is very important as if you miss it, the `View` will use it's specified value instead of calculated one according to weights) it will receive 50% value of it's container's width/height.

Comment: @Genadinik No problem, hope it helps!

Comment: it's recommended to use integer values for the weights , so that you can also have irrational fractions , like 1/3 .

Comment: @mosquito I wasn't able to get it quite right. Here is another question I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927632/android-2-column-layout-looks-messed-up-when-i-try-to-create-dynamic-layout-wi

Answer (score 1):

`android:layout_weight="1/2/3/4/5/..."` will be your new friend ;-)

Do not forget to also use `android:layout_width="0dip"`