# Android - 2-column layout looks messed up when I try to create dynamic layout widths

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:weightSum="1.0">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
         android:layout_weight=".8"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="0dip"        
         android:textSize="16sp"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" 
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="0dip"  
         android:layout_weight=".2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the snippet that references this in the parent screen

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="17sp"> 
</ListView>
```

[image]

and I am trying to have some text on the left side, and a > character on the right side so that the user knows to choose it.

Here is how I populate the list:

```
private List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps;
private SimpleAdapter adapter;

ListView list = null;       

    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    // My data
    fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.my_problems,
            new String[] {"train", "to"}, 
            new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL,  R.id.TO_CELL});        

                    for ( int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++ )
                    {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);                                

                        problem_title = o.getString("problem_title");
                        problem_id = o.getString("problem_id");
                        String has_new_comments = o.getString("has_new_comments");
                        String is_private = o.getString("is_private");

                        Problem p = new Problem ( );
                        p.setProblemId(problem_id);                         
                        p.setProblemName(problem_title);
                        p.setIsPrivate(is_private);
                        p.setHasNewComments(has_new_comments);

                        map.put("train", p.toString() );
                        map.put("to", ">");

                        fillMaps.add(map);
                        problems.add( p );                                                          
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But the screen looks like mess with the column on the left appearing right next to the column on the right with no space, and the ">" character is not lined up on the same column but it spaced randomly depending where the left column ends.

Any thoughts on what may be going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I have never tried using weights less than 1, so you might try multiplying everything by 10. Otherwise, use Hierarchy View to see where things are going wrong.

Comment: @CommonsWare what would you recommend the weights to be? I just wasn't aware using less than 1 isn't common. I need the left column to have about 80% of the width and the right column 20%

Comment: "what would you recommend the weights to be?" -- 8 and 2. Or 4 and 1. Or 80 and 20. The ratio is what matters. I only mention the less-than-1 issue because I cannot remember ever seeing it done. For all I know, it works correctly. BTW, since your two weights sum to your desired value, I would remove the `weightSum`.

Comment: @CommonsWare that didn't seem to make any difference :(

Comment: I just added a screen shot of the 2-column layout and how it is spaced out incorrectly.